# Find from a subset of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something like `Model.find(array_of_ids, :conditions => {:attribute => "something"})`

Where I will be returned all entries where attribute = something, but only from within that array of ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Model.where('id in (?)', array_of_ids).where(attribute: "something")
```

Comment: Couldn't find Model without an ID.  Removing the .find() returns the correct array, however.

Comment: Model.where("id in (?) and attribute = ?", array_of_ids, "something") seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

```
Model.where id: array_of_ids, attribute: 'something'
```